# implementing a Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>, order of the keys?

Tags: c#

I have the choice of where to put both key;

```
 Dictionary<key1, Dictionary<key2, int>>
 Dictionary<key2, Dictionary<key1, int>>
```

if key1 is 32x smaller than key2

which one should I implement to get maximum speed?

does it matter even matter?

is there a better way to implement that?

Comment: To implement what? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Try it both ways and measure. :)

Comment: @spender, implementing a fast lookup dictionary that need 2 keys

Comment: Value or Reference Type keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so after playing around i went with this solution;

```
  int[,][] myDict;
```

instead of

```
  Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>> myDict;
```

or a tuple or struct for both keys

Comment: So your keys are contiguous `int`s. You never said so. And how does that rhyme with a 32x size difference?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, they are not contiguous but they got a pattern, enum flag. there is a memory cost to my solution but what matter is speed which in this case win.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you get the best performance by implementing a composite key:

```
struct Key { key1; key2; }
```

Implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for it (better yet, the `IEquatable<Key>` interface).

With this pattern you only need one dictionary and one hash lookup.

Comment: If this is running as 64-bit code, and it's two int32, the whole struct would be 64-bit long? Is there any need to implement equals and gethashcode then?

Comment: Yes you probably don't want to use the default implementations because those are horrible. If you have Resharper you can codegen the functions in 3sec using `alt-ins`.

Comment: I'm going to try this later today and see the difference :-)

Comment: Hm, I was thinking about sorting, never mind.. :)

Comment: Just use a Tuple<> (and get Equals et al for free).

Comment: @HenkHolterman Tuple is a ref type causing heap allocations and indirection. I cannot imagine this would be faster here.

Comment: @usr, so after playing around i went with this solution; int[,][] myDict;